# java regular expression word without ending with dot

Tags: java, regex

I need to print the simple bind variable names in the SQL query.
I need to print the words starting with `:` character But NOT ending with dot  `.` character.
in this sample I need to print `pOrg`, `pBusinessId` but NOT the `parameter`.
The regular expression `="(:)(\\w+)^\\."` is not working.

### Could you help in correcting the regular expression.

Thanks
Peddi

```
public void testMethod(){ 
String regEx="(:)(\\w+)([^\\.])";  
String input= "(origin_table like 'I%' or (origin_table like 'S%' and        process_status =5))and header_id = NVL( :parameter.number1:NULL, header_id) and (orginization = :pOrg) and (businsess_unit = :pBusinessId";
Pattern pattern;
Matcher matcher;

    pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    String grp = null;

    while(matcher.find()){

        grp = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(grp);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also want to match `:NULL`?

Comment: And why it shouldn't match `:NULL` OR `: parameter`?

Comment: Ideally I need to exclude ":NULL" with case insensitive , but thought that might complicate the regular expression.

Comment: ok try: `:(?!NULL)\\w+\\b(?!\\.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with something like

```
String regEx = "(:)(\\w+)\\b(?![.])";
```

- `(:)(\\w+)\\b` will make sure that you are matching only entire words starting with `:`
- `(?![.])` is [look behind mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which makes sure that after found word there is no `.`

This regex will also allow `:NULL` so if there is some reason why it shouldn't be matched share it with us.

---

Anyway to exclude `NULL` from results you can use

```
String regEx = "(:)(\\w+)\\b(?![.])(?<!:NULL)";
```

To make regex case insensitive so `NULL` could also match `null` compile this pattern with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: You have placed the `\\b` very cleverly in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^:.*?[^.]$");
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/eqtnk)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using camelcase, you can actually simplify things a bit when it comes to excluding `:NULL`:

`:([a-z][\\w]+)\\b(?!\\.)`

And `$1` will return your variable names.

Alternative that doesn't rely on negative lookahead:

`:([a-z][\\w]+)\\b(?:[^\\.]|$)`